# Using jQuery, want to count the number of elements with specific class occuring after a class

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to get the count of number of right columns occurring after a left column using jQuery.

For eg: in the below structure, the results should be

1st leftColumn = 3;
2nd leftColumn = 1 and so on...

```
<div class="panel leftColumn"></div>
<div class="panel rightColumn"></div>
<div class="panel rightColumn"></div>
<div class="panel rightColumn"></div>
<div class="panel leftColumn"></div>
<div class="panel rightColumn"></div>
```

Note: My jQuery figures out which column the divs fall into and adds the class name as appropriate, so it would be great if a solution could be fit into my code below

```
var dataHolder = $j("div.panel").first().offset().left;

if($j(this).offset().left == dataHolder){
                $j(this).addClass("leftColumn");
            }
            else{
                $j(this).addClass("rightColumn");
            }
```

Comment: Can there be other elements mixed in that are neither `leftColumn` or `rightColumn`?

Comment: Initially there is no class marked as leftColumn or rightColumn - I have written a jQuery script to detect which column the div falls into and then added the class "leftColum" or "rightColumn".

Comment: Great. So, can there be other elements mixed in that are neither `leftColumn` or `rightColumn`?

Comment: no, there would be no such elements as my code handles adding classes to the div's with classname = panel.

Comment: Good deal. It's just that that's fairly relevant, because if there could be, JesseB's answer would be right (because it filters them out) but Esailija's wouldn't be (because it doesn't). Since other elements won't exist, they're both correct.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, true but I am not writing answers with a crystal ball, if you give me a html structure then it better match the real html structure that you have. Applying filter just adds redundant overhead, there is enough of it already from using jQuery =)

Comment: @Esailija: Wasn't criticizing you at all. I was commenting on the question, not the answers, if you follow me. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.leftColumn').each(function (i) {
    console.log('leftColumn ' + (i + 1) + ': ' + 
        $(this).nextUntil('.leftColumn', '.rightColumn').length); 
});
```

Here's the **[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/CaMCD/)** showing it in action.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Added the jsfiddle with the intention of adding the code later on in an edit.

Comment: `@JesseB`: Being first isn't that important. At a minimum, post the code, ideally an explanation, perhaps a reference, and (optionally) a live link. Revising is great, but your first answer should be sufficient even if you end up not being able to revise (for whatever reason). People **will** see your first effort, and comment and vote accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = $(".leftColumn").map(function() {
    return $(this).nextUntil(".leftColumn").length;
}).toArray();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DBg2L/4/

Returns an array `[3,1]`, which means 3 for the first and 1 for the second and so on..